# I'm trying to read a .txt DataGridView in VB Express 2010 and search for contents. How do I do it? (content is relevant)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

This is my first time on this site and I would like help very much.
I made a program in VB 2010 Express to try and read a .txt file into an DataGridView. I got it to read in and I have a function to search through surnames and search through date of birth. The way I want it to search is so that if I type in the month (02) for February, then it will list all the people with the DOB month as February. The surnames work fine but the DOB doesn't. Whenever I try to search the month February (02) The DataGridView becomes blank. http://puu.sh/8asUD.png (picture of addressgrid/datagridview going blank) The contents of the .txt file are exactly:

> Jackson,Samantha,2 Heather Row,Basingstoke,RG21 3SD,01256 135434,23/04/1973,sam.jackson@hotmail.com,Vickers,Jonathan,18 Saville Gardens,Reading,RG3 5FH,01196 678254,04/02/1965,the_man@btinternet.com,Morris,Sally,The Old Lodge, Hook,RG23 5RD,01256 728443,19/02/1975,smorris@fgh.co.uk,Cobbly,Harry,345 The High Street,Guildford,GU2 4KJ,01458 288763,30/03/1960,harry.cobbly@somewhere.org.uk,Khan,Jasmine,36 Hever Avenue,Edenbridge,TN34 4FG,01569 276524,28/02/1980,jas.khan@hotmail.com,Vickers,Harriet,45 Sage Gardens,Brighton,BN3 2FG,01675 662554,04/04/1968,harriet.vickers@btinternet.com

Here's the code for **THE ENTIRE FORM**:

```
    Public Class AddressBook
Structure Address
    Public Forename As String
    Public Surname As String
    Public Address1 As String
    Public Address2 As String
    Public Postcode As String
    Public Phonenumber As String
    Public DOB As String
    Public Email As String
End Structure
Public Addressbook(40) As Address
Public recordcounter As Integer = 0
Public readfile As Boolean = False

Private Sub btt_read_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btt_read.Click
    'Declare Textfile

    If System.IO.File.Exists("addressbook.txt") = False Then
        MsgBox("This text file doesn't exist")
    End If
    Dim Addressfile As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\DirtyMike\Desktop\123\Controlled Assessment\addressbook.txt", True)
    Dim loopcounter As Integer
    Dim filecontent As String
    Dim temparray() As String
    If readfile = False Then
        filecontent = Addressfile.ReadLine
        temparray = filecontent.Split(",")
        readfile = True
        'Display the data
        For loopcounter = 0 To (temparray.Length - 7) Step 8
            Addressbook(recordcounter).Surname = temparray(loopcounter + 0)
            Addressbook(recordcounter).Forename = temparray(loopcounter + 1)
            Addressbook(recordcounter).Address1 = temparray(loopcounter + 2)
            Addressbook(recordcounter).Address2 = temparray(loopcounter + 3)
            Addressbook(recordcounter).Postcode = temparray(loopcounter + 4)
            Addressbook(recordcounter).Phonenumber = temparray(loopcounter + 5)
            Addressbook(recordcounter).DOB = temparray(loopcounter + 6)
            Addressbook(recordcounter).Email = temparray(loopcounter + 7)
            recordcounter = recordcounter + 1

        Next
        Addressfile.Close()
        REM Display the Data
        For loopcounter = 0 To recordcounter - 1

            AddressGrid.Rows.Add()
            AddressGrid.Rows.Item(loopcounter).Cells(0).Value = Addressbook(loopcounter).Surname
            AddressGrid.Rows.Item(loopcounter).Cells(1).Value = Addressbook(loopcounter).Forename
            AddressGrid.Rows.Item(loopcounter).Cells(2).Value = Addressbook(loopcounter).Address1
            AddressGrid.Rows.Item(loopcounter).Cells(3).Value = Addressbook(loopcounter).Address2
            AddressGrid.Rows.Item(loopcounter).Cells(6).Value = Addressbook(loopcounter).DOB
            AddressGrid.Rows.Item(loopcounter).Cells(7).Value = Addressbook(loopcounter).Email
            AddressGrid.Rows.Item(loopcounter).Cells(5).Value = Addressbook(loopcounter).Phonenumber
            AddressGrid.Rows.Item(loopcounter).Cells(4).Value = Addressbook(loopcounter).Postcode
        Next
        'Display the data from the file.
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub bttsurname_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btt_searchsur.Click
    AddressGrid.Rows.Clear()
    Dim surname As String
    Dim loopcounter As Integer
    Dim positioncounter As Integer
    surname = txt_surname.Text

    For loopcounter = 0 To recordcounter
        If Addressbook(loopcounter).Surname = surname Then

            Me.AddressGrid.Rows.Add()
            Me.AddressGrid.Rows.Item(positioncounter).Cells(0).Value = Me.Addressbook(loopcounter).Surname
            Me.AddressGrid.Rows.Item(positioncounter).Cells(1).Value = Me.Addressbook(loopcounter).Forename
            Me.AddressGrid.Rows.Item(positioncounter).Cells(2).Value = Me.Addressbook(loopcounter).Address1
            Me.AddressGrid.Rows.Item(positioncounter).Cells(3).Value = Me.Addressbook(loopcounter).Address2
            Me.AddressGrid.Rows.Item(positioncounter).Cells(4).Value = Me.Addressbook(loopcounter).Postcode
            Me.AddressGrid.Rows.Item(positioncounter).Cells(5).Value = Me.Addressbook(loopcounter).Phonenumber
            Me.AddressGrid.Rows.Item(positioncounter).Cells(6).Value = Me.Addressbook(loopcounter).DOB
            Me.AddressGrid.Rows.Item(positioncounter).Cells(7).Value = Me.Addressbook(loopcounter).Email
            positioncounter = positioncounter + 1
        End If

    Next

End Sub
Private Sub btt_menu_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btt_menu.Click
    Menu1.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btt_searchdob_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btt_searchdob.Click

    AddressGrid.Rows.Clear()
    Dim DOB As String
    Dim loopcounter, positioncounter As Integer
    Dim MonthA As String
    DOB = txt_DOB.Text
    MonthA = Mid(DOB, 4, 2)

    positioncounter = 0
    For loopcounter = 0 To recordcounter
        If MonthA = Mid(Addressbook(loopcounter).DOB, 4, 2) Then
            Me.AddressGrid.Rows.Add()
            Me.AddressGrid.Rows.Item(positioncounter).Cells(0).Value = Me.Addressbook(loopcounter).Surname
            Me.AddressGrid.Rows.Item(positioncounter).Cells(1).Value = Me.Addressbook(loopcounter).Forename
            Me.AddressGrid.Rows.Item(positioncounter).Cells(2).Value = Me.Addressbook(loopcounter).Address1
            Me.AddressGrid.Rows.Item(positioncounter).Cells(3).Value = Me.Addressbook(loopcounter).Address2
            Me.AddressGrid.Rows.Item(positioncounter).Cells(4).Value = Me.Addressbook(loopcounter).Postcode
            Me.AddressGrid.Rows.Item(positioncounter).Cells(5).Value = Me.Addressbook(loopcounter).Phonenumber
            Me.AddressGrid.Rows.Item(positioncounter).Cells(6).Value = Me.Addressbook(loopcounter).DOB
            Me.AddressGrid.Rows.Item(positioncounter).Cells(7).Value = Me.Addressbook(loopcounter).Email
            positioncounter = positioncounter + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btt_clear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btt_clear.Click
    AddressGrid.Rows.Clear()

    For loopcounter = 0 To recordcounter - 1

        AddressGrid.Rows.Add()
        AddressGrid.Rows.Item(loopcounter).Cells(0).Value = Addressbook(loopcounter).Surname
        AddressGrid.Rows.Item(loopcounter).Cells(1).Value = Addressbook(loopcounter).Forename
        AddressGrid.Rows.Item(loopcounter).Cells(2).Value = Addressbook(loopcounter).Address1
        AddressGrid.Rows.Item(loopcounter).Cells(3).Value = Addressbook(loopcounter).Address2
        AddressGrid.Rows.Item(loopcounter).Cells(4).Value = Addressbook(loopcounter).Postcode
        AddressGrid.Rows.Item(loopcounter).Cells(5).Value = Addressbook(loopcounter).Phonenumber
        AddressGrid.Rows.Item(loopcounter).Cells(6).Value = Addressbook(loopcounter).DOB
        AddressGrid.Rows.Item(loopcounter).Cells(7).Value = Addressbook(loopcounter).Email

    Next
    'Display the data from the file.
End Sub

Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
```

End Class

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! (P.S. Apologies for the poor tags, they're probably wrong.)

Comment: We can't see if you are parsing the text file correctly.  Is all of the data in AddressBook correct?  What does the txt_DOB.Text field say?  What is the value of MonthA?  You are in a much better position to debug this than we are.

Comment: I'm sorry, as I said, I'm new to this site. I don't have much of an idea what I'm doing. Should I enter all the code from the program here? I'm also not sure as to what parsing means. Thanks for replying!

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.  Parse means to read the text file and separate the strings into their data elements.  Is that the problem?  We don't know.  The only conclusions I can make is that either the Addressbook collection you have doesn't have the data from the text file, or your DOB information you are trying to filter on is wrong.  These are things you aren't telling us, nor showing us.

Comment: Simply put, I'm asking why isn't my program displaying the name that is linked the the month whenever the number of the month, 02, is typed in. I'll just include my code for the entire thing, I'm new to VB and not exactly experienced with it. I think I'm parsing it correctly but I'm unsure.

Comment: I have added the code to the full form in the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can add some Symbol into the text this process will be easy to fetch Like:

TextFileData = %Your Name,Age,Address%Other Name, Other Age, Other Address,

You can use split ("%") to get the users information

Users = TextFileData.Split("%")

Then use split(",") to extract the information

Information = Users(0),Split(",")